# Can't npm install after including public github repo as dependency

Tags: git, npm

I have a public repo with just a series of .md markdown files that I want to pull into my `node_modules` each time I `npm install`, so that I can use that markdown content in my main website.

I (think) I have updated my `package.json` according to the npm docs here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls...

My `package.json` now has:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "repoName": "git://github.com/{orgName}/{repoName}.git"
  }
```

I have also tried the other short-hand methods, like: `"repo-name": "organization/repo-name"`

When I try to run `npm install` I get the follwing error:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/<user>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6be72c5b/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<user>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6be72c5b/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/<user>/.npm/_logs/2018-05-23T04_39_57_402Z-debug.log
```

The only additional information that log file gives is...

```
18 verbose Darwin 17.4.0
19 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
20 verbose node v7.0.0
21 verbose npm  v5.6.0
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong? Everything is groovy with npm when I don't have this dependency in.

Comment: Can you please link the repo so I can have a look :)

Comment: The repo where I am configuring `package.json` is private :/ Sorry. Only the dependency public.

Comment: ahh no worries, would you mind pasting your whole package.json file

Comment: Sure, updated it to include the whole package.json, with the name of the repos redacted.

Comment: Does the package you're installing, have a `package.json` file in it? From the error: `npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<user>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6be72c5b/package.json'`—this leads me to believe that the package you're trying to install doesn't have the correct files in it.

Comment: Oh! Didn't know the dependency repo needed npm too. I figured it npm would just dump the repo contents in a folder in my node_modules... Ill try that.

Comment: That was it, @Whymarrh! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this, filling in all the  with your stuff :)

```
"dependencies": {
    "GitRepo": "git+https://<token-from-github>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<GitRepo>.git"
}
```

Hope that helps :)
You should be able to ignore the x-oauth since its public

Answer (score 0):

@Whymarrh pointed out that I needed to init npm on the dependency repo.